# how to set custom interval to horizontal axis in Flex Charts

Tags: charts, flex3

I am trying to set custom step (interval) to my Line Chart's horizontal axis.
The chart gets its data from a grid. The grid has a lot of data and it is displayed accurately but because there are so many data points the horizontal axis is screwed up. I wanted to set a step on horizontal axis so that you get an idea when you see the graph without hovering the mouse on a data point! 
thanks for any help!
-Ali

---

[Flexi Comment Box](http://alimsyed.com/)

Comment: o pleaseeeee!    i really need help with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

heylo people! 
I have solved the mystery!!! 
just add a horrizontalAxisRenderers to your Chart
and set the property canDropLabels to true!

```
  <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
                <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{horiAxis_B}" canDropLabels="true"/>
            </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
```

axis being the name of the axis
you are done!! 
but if you still have questions, you can always contact me here: 
[Alimsyed.com](http://alimsyed.com)